# List view with customize row layout and base adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I am creating a `ListView`. I have created two XML files, in the first one I created a layout, and in the **Second xml file -** a ListView. I want first layout to be applied to the ListView row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This possible using **BaseAdapter** and **ListView**. I found a very impressive explanation about your issue .Please have a look on this URL

[List View With Images](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/09/listview-example-in-android-with-image.html)

Comment: i  can not rate you as my reputation is not enough to do it