# Android Listview with different layout for each row depeding on rows values

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I am trying to determine the best way to have a single `Listview` containing different rows styles.

I searched alot and found some tricks using `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType(int position)`, to let the listview layout changes depending on position and that was not what I'm looking for.

What I'm trying to do is to change the listview layout depeding on a textview value on the row itself.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the textview you want to track is set somewhere in your adapter, isn't it?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you cant achieve this with the methods listed above, if you know how many views you have, then create an .xml for each one of them and then in the `getView()` inflate the corresponding  layout depending on the value of your `textview`. You then return this row and it should then work.

Answer (score 0):

well, this is exactly what you need to do.

override the `getViewTypeCout` to return the amount of types you have.
override the `getItemViewType` and determine the type according to the position (or item to show)

after you do that, just use this in your `getView` like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(getItemViewType(position) == FIRST_VIEW_TYPE) {
        // inflate first view
    } else {
        // inflate seconde view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I searched alot and found some tricks using getViewTypeCount() and getItemViewType(int position), to let the listview layout changes depending on position and that was not what I'm looking for.

Yes, it is.

> What I'm trying to do is to change the listview layout depeding on a textview value on the row itself.

No, you are not. You are trying to "change the listview layout depeding [sic] on" some text that you plan on putting into "a textview value on the row itself". As mr_archano points out, this `TextView` is not magically getting a value -- it is getting a value based on something *you* put there by one means or another.

Hence:

- Override `getViewTypeCount()` to return the number of distinct possible row types
- Override `getItemViewType()` to return a value from 0 to `getViewTypeCount()-1` based upon *the text* that you plan on pouring into the `TextView`
- Ensure that your `getView()` or `bindView()` implementation is aware of the different view types and handles them accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the TextView inside the ListView Row must come from some data you have defined (probably an ArrayList or similar I'm assuming), so what you have to do is check what kind of view you want to draw based on that data before drawing the ROW, this is done on the getView() method.

getView() is called when the ListView wants to render a given element, you're thinking it doesn't have to do with position but it does. You know the TextView contents before drawing them, so parse that value and use the type of layout you want in getView dynamically ;).

Read this if it is still not clear: [Android custom listview row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346348/android-custom-listview-row)